# Bluehost wont show photos

Tags: html, css, photo, bluehost

I'm new on Bluehost i have a simple site where is just pictures and it works outside of Bluehost, but now i have put it on bluehost i can see everything else but it says picture not found : GET http://*****.com/1.jpg 404 (Not Found).
[image]

these i have put inside public_html,  index.html and under it  5 pictures.

```html
   <img src="1.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found, you have uploaded image which was saved in server as text.

check your image type (text/x-generic) which means your file uploaded as text.

Are the images stored on your computer with extension: JPG (capitals)?
If so, try renaming then so the extension is lower case and re-upload.
Seems to be a 'feature' in FileManager that JPG is listed as text/x-generic and jpg as img/x-generic.

Source - https://x10hosting.com/community/threads/uploaded-image-appears-as-text-x-generic.103206/

Please rename and upload again and let me know if this helps.

Happy Coding!

Comment: I got it working with your help, i did not know that there is difference saving between .jpg and .JPG pictures were saved JPG (capitals).

Comment: Yes I experienced the same issue with Bluehost.  I had one image that was .JPG capitals and when I looked at it through Bluehost's filemanager, it says it is text/x-generic.  Changing it to jpg small letters solved this issue.  However, I think Bluehost should fix this to accept JPG as well as jpg as an image.

Answer (score 0):

you have to give proper path 
like

```
<img src="photos/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
```

make sure the image is in same folder

Comment: pictures works in my pc like that, and on bluehost as i said everthing is in public_html, index and 5 pictures.

Comment: Did not help got same error message

Comment: i hope its not related to image availability, check image type it was saved as text